# TextInputLayout hint color not match in floating and normal state

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

[image: Hint color when textInputLayout label floating]

[image: Hint color when label is not floating]

I want hint color to be same (pink) in both state.

**What I am doing**

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayoutError" 
    parent="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPink</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPink</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>



textinputlayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearence_App_TextInputLayoutError);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the TextInputLayout that holds the EditText, add:

```
android:textColorHint="someColor"
```

**OR**

You need to change your style.xml. Because your parent should be like below.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <!--EditText hint color-->
            <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/default_app_white(This should be your color code)</item>
           <!-- TextInputLayout text color-->
            <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/default_app_green</item>
            <!-- EditText line color when EditText on-focus-->
            <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/default_app_green</item>
            <!-- EditText line color when EditText  in un-focus-->
            <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/default_app_white</item>
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a color you require in your `colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorAccent">#cf376b</color>
```

Then add the line `android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"` in your `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

Like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Your Hint" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```